# hbase consistency problems when update span across multiple rows

Tags: transactions, hbase

```
sample hbase table -    


+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| username X + username Y who is following X | full name of username Y |
+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| AK+foo                                     | James Foo               |
| AK+bar                                     | Jimmy Bar               |
| AK+baz                                     | Ricky Baz               |
| AK+troy                                    | Troy                    |
| foo+bar                                    | Jimmy Bar               |
| foo+AK                                     | AK                      |
+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

My understanding is that hbase doesnt offer transaction, which spans across multiple rows.
In that case, assuming i want to delete user AK, which spans across multiple rows.
How is the delete operation handled, without breaking consistentcy.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I realized that `hbase` does not have transactions,
i.e. it cannot guarantee the atomicity across multiple rows.
Hence, in the above case, it is often the application's responsibility
if a failure happens after only a partial write succeeds (for example: 1 row is deleted, 2nd is not).

So the application will need to handle the inconsistent data and try to make it consistent.